# How to install dsbulk on mac?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, dsbulk

I have been following the [official documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/install/6.7/install/installDSbulk.html) for installing dsbulk loader but in vain. In the documentation, it says download and install but all that is instructed is to download and extract the zip file. However, typing `dsbulk` in any directory where it is downloaded and extracted does not work as well. I receive an error:
`zsh: command not found: dsbulk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use it that way, just put directory where you extracted it into `PATH` variable, like this:

```
export PATH=directory_with_dsbulk/bin:$PATH
```

or use full path name to run it, like:

```
directory_with_dsbulk/bin/dsbulk ...options...
```